# The protocol is not available, Signalwire Relay Client Subscription

Tags: react-native, phone-call, relay, jssip, signalwire

I am trying to subscribe to Signalwire phone numbers using Relay SDK with following code:

```
this.client1 = new Relay({
        project: 'myprojectid',
        token: jwtToken,
    })
    
    this.client1.subscribe({
        protocol: "WSS",
        channels: ["channel1", "channel2"]
    }).then(r => {
        console.log(r);
    })
```

It throws an error:

```
"code": -32004,
 "message": "Ignored 'blade.subscription' request because the protocol is not available"
```

I tried searching documentation, but could not find about how I can subscribe to channels using Relay SDK. I have also tried other protocols such as "TLS", "TCP" or "http, https"  etc but did not succeed.
Please share any documentation for subscribing to channels or phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible from this post to tell if you're using the SignalWire SDKs exclusively, if you're working from third party tools, or if you're doing your own setup. Depending on that and on what you're specifically looking to do with these, this might be a question of setup or it might not be possible.

With all that in mind, if you could reach out to SignalWire support (from your SignalWire space, select 'Help and Support' at the top right and then Submit a New Support Request) we can take a look at your setup and work through this with you.